# Content Provider error: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x234590

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have implemented a Content Provider, it is resulting in following error

> 04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x234590

The query in Content Provider is

```
Cursor cursor = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null,
            sortOrder);
```

and call to Content Provider is

```
cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[] { ContactTableMetaData.ABC,
            ContactTableMetaData.MNP }, ContactTableMetaData.XYZ + "=?",
            new String[] { "phonenumber1", "phonenumber2", "phonenumber3",
                    "phonenumber4", "phonenumber5", "email1", "email2", "email3",
                    "email4", "email5" }, null);
```

Complete logcat is

```
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x234590
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_bind_string(Native Method)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:241)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.bindString(SQLiteQuery.java:182)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:48)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:330)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:280)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at com.wissenways.helper.VoiceAppContactContentProvider.query(VoiceAppContactContentProvider.java:171)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:163)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:245)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at com.wissenways.checkcontacts.DisplayGreatPeople.onCreate(DisplayGreatPeople.java:45)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-25 00:25:16.856: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  ... 11 more
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String selection = ContactTableMetaData.XYZ + "=?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { "phonenumber1", "phonenumber2", "phonenumber3",
                    "phonenumber4", "phonenumber5", "email1", "email2", "email3",
                    "email4", "email5" }
```

The amount of `?` must match the amount of `selectionArgs`. If you provide 10 items then the `selection` has to have 10 `?`.

The N-th `?` in `selection` is replaced by the N-th item in `selectionArgs`.

Edit: If you want to check if ContactTableMetaData.XYZ is any of those then either do

```
String selection = ContactTableMetaData.XYZ + "=? OR " + ContactTableMetaData.XYZ + "=? OR " + ...
```

or

```
String selection = ContactTableMetaData.XYZ + " IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ..)"
```

I would prefer the second one :)

Comment: Thanks. I want to check the value of selection to all the 10 values. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getWhereStr(String columnName, int selectionArgsSize) {
    String delim = ",";
    final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    buf.append(columnName + " IN (");
    for (int i = 0; i < selectionArgsSize; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            buf.append(delim);
        }
        buf.append("?");
    }
    buf.append(")");
    return buf.toString(); 
}
```